# The best method for the Ajax web service call which is in remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I don't know whether I am asking a correct question or not, but it is very important to know about it for me right now. So, what the question is which one of the below two methods is preferable and why?

1. The calling of webservice which is in remote server using Ajax webservice directly.
2. Adding that remote web service as a web reference to my solution and calling one local web service using Ajax and in that web method then I'd call my referenced webservice.

In the above two methods which one should be preferable, and I am working on ASP.NET project. Hope I am clear with my question and Please help me with an explanation.

Comment: Both are fine. Use approach that works for your case. Some services are easier to use from server side code and some may not have CORS, but there no way to provide concrete recommendations based on information provided.

Comment: Hello @Alexei Levenkov thank you for your suggestion and which one is secure and which is the best one for giving response in less time also.